# Build FFmpeg with Freetype2 for ARM

Tags: android, linux, ffmpeg, configure, freetype

I'm trying to build FFmpeg binary file with freetype library included ( I need it for drawtext filter ). Unfortunately I cannot configure ffmpeg properly and every try ends with "freetype not found" error.

PS I've tried to build guardian-ffmpeg project but i'm getting errors during configure process.

PS2 Building plain ffmpeg works perfectly well

Configuration script:

```
make distclean &./configure --target-os=linux \
--cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=armv7-a \
--enable-libfreetype --enable-filter=drawtext \ #!Freetype params
--disable-network \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--enable-protocol=file \
--sysroot=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/platforms/${ANDROID_API_VERSION}/arch-arm \
--prefix=build/armeabi-v7a \
--disable-asm \
--extra-cflags='-DANDROID -Ifreetype2/ -I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/sources/cxx-stl/system/include -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp' \
--extra-ldflags='-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Lfreetype2/ -L../android-libs -Wl,-rpath-link,../android-libs' \
--extra-cxxflags='-Wno-multichar -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti'
make -j6 && make install || exit 0
```

Directories sctructure:

```
ffmpeg/
   -ffmpeg dirs/
   -freetype2/
   -rest of ffmpeg files ( including configure, make, etc )
```

I've checked patch sources in guardian-project and I've found that ffmpeg configure file might need some changes in `require_libfreetype` method?!

Thanks in advance ( and sorry for my bad english )

EDIT:
Building on OSX Mavericks,
Last 3 lines of `config.log`; OSX hasn't got `pkg-config` therefore `false` in 2nd line:

```
require_libfreetype
false --exists --print-errors freetype
ERROR: freetype not found
```

EDIT:
SOLUTION!!!

I've manadged to solve my issue. I've used Xubuntu 14.04 64bit + Freetype 2.5.3 + newest FFmpeg repo + install linux package "pkg_config" and small modifications in ffmpeg configure script ( find pkg_config and check initialization variable )

config file for freetype:

```
NDK_BASE=/home/dpc/Documents/android-ndk-r9d/
NDK_PROCESSOR=x86_64
NDK_PLATFORM_LEVEL=9
NDK_ABI=arm
NDK_COMPILER_VERSION=4.6

# Android NDK setup
NDK_PLATFORM_LEVEL=9
NDK_ABI=arm
NDK_COMPILER_VERSION=4.6
NDK_SYSROOT=$NDK_BASE/platforms/android-$NDK_PLATFORM_LEVEL/arch-$NDK_ABI
NDK_UNAME=`uname -s | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
if [ $NDK_ABI = "x86" ]; then
    HOST=i686-linux-android
    NDK_TOOLCHAIN=$NDK_ABI-$NDK_COMPILER_VERSION
else
    HOST=$NDK_ABI-linux-androideabi
    NDK_TOOLCHAIN=$HOST-$NDK_COMPILER_VERSION
fi
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASE=$NDK_BASE/toolchains/$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/prebuilt/$NDK_UNAME-$NDK_PROCESSOR
echo "dpc:" $NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASE

CC="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASE/bin/$HOST-gcc --sysroot=$NDK_SYSROOT"
LD=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASE/bin/$HOST-ld
STRIP=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_BASE/bin/$HOST-strip
PREFIX=$(pwd)/build

simple_config(){
make clean
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --without-zlib --without-png --prefix=
make -j4
make install DESTDIR=$(pwd)
}

complex_config(){

    ./configure \
    CC="$CC" \
    LD="$LD" \
    CFLAGS="-std=gnu99 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -marm -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon" \
    --host=$HOST \
    --with-sysroot="$NDK_SYSROOT" \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-shared \
    --prefix=$PREFIX
    --without-bzip2

    make -j4
    make install
}


make clean
complex_config
```

ffmpeg config file:

```
#!/bin/sh

ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH=/home/dpc/Documents/android-ndk-r9d
ANDROID_API_VERSION=android-9
#export PATH=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}:${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:$PATH
export PATH=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}:${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:$PATH
echo $PATH
#export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/dpc/Documents/freetype-2.5.3/build/lib/pkgconfig/
#echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH

#armv7-a neon
#export ARCH=armeabi-v7a-neon
#./configure --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=armv7-a --sysroot=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/platforms/${ANDROID_API_VERSION}/arch-arm --disable-avdevice --disable-decoder=h264_vdpau  --prefix=build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-DANDROID -I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/sources/cxx-stl/system/include -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -L../android-libs -Wl,-rpath-link,../android-libs' --extra-cxxflags='-Wno-multichar -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti'
#make -j6 && make install && make distclean|| exit 0

#armv7-a
export ARCH=armeabi-v7a
./configure --target-os=linux \
--cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- \
--arch=arm \
--enable-libfreetype \
--cpu=armv7-a \
--sysroot=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/platforms/${ANDROID_API_VERSION}/arch-arm \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-decoder=h264_vdpau  \
--prefix=build/armeabi-v7a \
--extra-cflags='-DANDROID -I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/sources/cxx-stl/system/include -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp' \
--extra-ldflags='-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -L../android-libs -Wl,-rpath-link,../android-libs' \
--extra-cxxflags='-Wno-multichar -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti'
make -j6 && make install && make distclean|| exit 0
```

Hope it helps someone (cc: @SinhHo )

Comment: Can you post the error output?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure how to deal with it, maybe you can compile first libfreetype, and then the main makefile.

Comment: I know, it is how I'm doing it now... Problem is how to inject freetype dependency to ffmpeg configure script

Comment: Maybe you should change the name of freetype2 folder to libfreetype.

Comment: I also got this problem. Have you resolved it?

Comment: @SinhHo Somehow I've succesfully compiled it ( and it works very well ). I will post the answer later today.

Comment: @PawelCala: Thanks for your reply and kindness. But I would like to understand your main change to fix this issue. Can you show me the code line which is the fix of this issue.

Comment: @SinhHo Sorry, just noticed your comment. Problem with building ffmpeg with freetype was lack of pkg_config that's why I had to build it on linux and install pkg_config package. Also you need to open ffmpeg configure script and check initialization of $pkg_config. I had to change it from "pkg_config" to "pkg-config". This should help you ( i hope )

Comment: Hi, good topic! Tel me please what is the binary ffmpeg file size for arm?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when cross compiled `ffmpeg` for android with `freetype` support on Mac.

Following is the error ouput

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: /var/folders/f0/b79d4kbs6cd1gcgt39gpw7t80000gn/T//ffconf.2zxiYMYG.m: Objective-C compiler not installed on this system
require_libfreetype
false --exists --print-errors freetype2
ERROR: freetype2 not found
```

So I thought the error was caused by `pkg-config`.

My solution was adding `freetype`'s pkgconfig file to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and specifying the `pkg-config` which install from port.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=../freetype-2.6.3/out/armeabi/lib/pkgconfig
./configure ... --pkg-config=/opt/local/bin/pkg-config ...
```

**Note**

I built `freetype` library from android standalone toolchain with configuration below

```
export CFLAGS="-fPIC"
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--with-png=no --enable-shared=no --prefix=out/armeabi
```

Hope it would helpful to anyone has similar problems.

Comment: can you help me? im trying to do the same, and i sucessfully compiled all dependencies i need for ffmpeg on android (including freetype ) but it still says 'ERROR: freetype2 not found using pkg-config'. I tried to what you said but didn't work